# Apache Camel TCP client communicate to a server

Tags: tcp, apache-camel, netty4

I am new to apache camel. What I am trying to do is I have exposed and Rest api to get data.
From that I need to communicate to an existing TCP server(Simple java server application) to retrieve data and send back to a client. What I have picked is Apache camel to do this integration.

```
 rest()
                .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
                .get("/weather2/{city}").outType(WeatherDto.class).to("direct:get-weather-data")

from("direct:get-weather-data")
                .process(this::setTCPMsg)
                .to("netty://tcp://127.0.0.1:9898")
```

Above is the way I have defined the routes but when I try to run the appication I get below eror

**org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route5 at: >>> To[netty://tcp://127.0.0.1:9898] <<< in route: Route(route5)[From[direct:get-weather-data] -> [process[Proc... because of No endpoint could be found for: netty://tcp://127.0.0.1:9898, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.**

Please advice How to solve this issue.

Comment: do you have the camel-netty dependency added to your project ?

Comment: @LucaBurgazzoli yes that was the mistake I have made Thanks for the support